# cant get to the sub elements on xml file

Tags: php, xml, file, foreach, echo

```
foreach($xml->property as $property ){
   foreach($property as $type){
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($property->id);
echo "ID: ".$id."<br/>";
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($type->uk);
echo "Type: ".$type."<br/>";
```

}
}

I want to echo the elements of the xml file now, the id is echoing okay but the type i can't get to it, and if i do this with the code above than the loop is double the id and the type is getting but not working as i want so how do i get the sub element with out foreach.. ?

EDIT: also i need them something like this because after the echo they need to be added in to a database..

exmp

```
<propery>
<ID>R123412</ID>
<type>
<uk>Apartmen</uk>
</type>
</propery>
```

Comment: is the value you want always in `<type><uk>`? Or could it be `<type><usa>`etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<propery>
<ID>R123412</ID>
<type>
<uk>Apartmen</uk>
</type>
</propery>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

//print_r($xml);
foreach ($xml as $key => $value) {  
    if (is_object($value))
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            echo "   ".$v;// because is object meens somthing under (the)
                   //you can also filter by keyname($key) 
        }
    echo "   ".$value; //this is the ID, you can also filter by keyname($key) 

}
```

and the result is:
R123412 Apartmen

Comment: This works like a charm but the thing is i need the values to be inserted them in to a database so this does not solve my problem